# Docusign - Can we get a copy of signed documents for our database automatically?

Tags: docusignapi

We would like to get/download/retrieve a copy of all signed DocuSign document pdfs to store in our database with the other associated data like name, date etc...  Is this possible to obtain in an automated fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either API or there is a desktop application called as DocuSign Retrieve -  https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/retrieve-quick-start-guide.pdf to download the DocuSign envelopes in a drive. Or you can use DocuSign Connect as well - https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf